# Why is my program skipping to the last line of inputs? (Python 3)

Tags: python

I am trying to take data in this input form:

```
5 
+ 3
* 7
+ 10
* 2
% 11
```

and perform the operations (starting with the 5 as the initial integer value) sequentially, coming up with a final value at the end. Here is the code I have right now and I am having trouble figuring out why it is skipping to the end. I have commented out certain parts to try and find the root of the problem, so don't worry about those:

```
initValue = int(input())
while input() != '':
    if '+' in input():
        lineList = input().split()
        print(lineList)
        #initValue = initValue + int(lineList[1])
        #print(initValue)
    elif '*' in input():
        lineList = input().split()
        print(lineList)
        #initValue = initValue * int(lineList[1])
        #print(initValue)
    elif '%' in input():
        lineList = input().split()
        print(lineList)
```

My input/output looks like this:

```
5
+ 3
* 7
+ 10
* 2
* 3
+ 1
% 11
['%', '11']
```

I am still just starting with python, so sorry if I'm making a really dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call function `input()`, it reads the whole next line and returns it. If you called it *with* the prompt parameter (as you ought to), you would know what exactly is happening.

So, your first `int(input())` reads `5`. The next one (in the `while` loop header) reads `+ 3` and discards it, because you never save the returned value. The next `input` in the `if '+'` statement reads `* 7` and discards it again, etc.

What you need is to make one single call to `input()` in the loop, assign the return value to a variable, and perform all checks on that variable.